# ASP CORE and webpack in VS2019: how to configure IIS Express to proxy js/css requests to webpack devserver?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-2.2

Code like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/main.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

started on IIS Express requests the files using IIS Express port, when I need return those files from webpack devserver that works on another port.

There is an article how to ["switch"](https://www.mattburkedev.com/integrate-webpack-and-asp-dot-net-mvc-slash-webapi/) configurations and "put" required port to `<link>` and `<script>` references, but here should be much more easy to instruct IIS Express (or self hosted ASP Core app) to proxy requests for `css` and `js`.

Unfortunatly this doesn't work (has no effect):

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        proxyaddress="http://localhost:55510"
        bypassonlocal="false"
      />
      <!--<bypasslist>
        <add address="^((?!\/dist\/).)*$" />
      </bypasslist>-->
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

How to configure IISEXpress or (selfhosted app) to proxy requests for `/dist/*.js` and `/dist/*.css` to the `webpack devserver`?

PS [It seems](https://sensibledev.com/reactjs-webpack-and-asp-net-standard/) those developers who are working with VS+webpack/devserver prefer to configure `webpack devserver` to proxy  requests for html/json/images/fonts to IISExpress (solving the same way but from another end). Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Just write the middleware that do the proxy"

solves it.

I have create nuget package for it: [DashboardCode.AspNetCore.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DashboardCode.AspNetCore.Http/)

GitHub: https://github.com/DashboardCode/AspNetCore

First add this to the Startup.cs

```
using DashboardCode.AspNetCore.Http;
```

Then add this to `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton( new DevProxyMiddlewareSettings(new PathString("/dist"), new Uri("http://localhost:55555")));
```

Then add this to the `Startup.Configure:`

```
app.UseMiddleware<DevProxyMiddleware>();
```

After this all GET requests like http://localhost:xxxx/dist/sample.js will be redirected to the http://localhost:55555/dist/sample.js

What is nice, it works for both cases: self-hosted and IISExpress hosted  application.